# CSV only contains last entry from file

Tags: regex, powershell, parsing

The CSV file only contains a partial entry from the last regex match.

I've used the ISE debugger and can verify it's finding matches.

```
$h = @{}
$a = @()
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\speterson\Documents\script\*.kiy | foreach {
    Get-Content $_ | foreach {
        if ($_ -match 'IF Ingroup\s+\(\s+\"(..+?)\"\s+\)') {
            $h.Group = $matches[1]          
        }
        if ($_ -match 'use\s+([A-Za-z]):"(\\\\..*?\\..*)\"'))  {
            $h.DriveLetter = $matches[1].ToUpper()
            $h.Path = $matches[2]
        }
    }

    $a += New-Object PSCustomObject -Property $h
}
$a | Export-Csv c:\temp\Whatever.csv -NoTypeInfo
```

The input files look like this, but have 1000+ lines in them:

```
IF Ingroup ( "RPC3WIA01NT" )
        use v: /del 
ENDIF   
IF Ingroup ( "JWA03KRONOSGLOBAL" )
        use v:"\\$homesrvr\$dept"
ENDIF    
IF Ingroup ( "P-USERS" )
        use p:'\\PServer\PDRIVE 
ENDIF
```

CSV file only shows:

```
GROUP    
P-USERS
```

I want to ignore the drive letters with the `/del`.

I'm trying to get a CSV file that shows

```
Group                Drive          Path
JWA03KRONOSGLOBAL    V              \\$homesrvr\$dept
P-USERS              P              \\PServer\PDRIVE
```

Comment: Inside the `Get-Content $_ | foreach {` pipeline you keep overwriting the items in `$h` everytime, and then only create an object from the last values outside the loop

Comment: Mathias - thanks for the quick reply.  So... move the $a+= 
Here:  $h.Path = $matches[2]
        } $a +=

is that correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly + maybe "reset" the hashtable with `$h = @{}` inside the loop so you don't carry over values from the previous file if a match fails

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two loops, one nested in the other. The outer loop processes each file from the `Get-ChildItem` call. The inner loop processes the content of the current file of the outer loop. However, since you're creating your objects *after* the inner loop finished you're only getting the last result from each processed file. Move object creation into the inner loop to get all results from all files.

I'd also recommend not re-using a hashtable. Re-using objects always bears the risk of having data carried over somewhere undesired. Hashtable creation is so inexpensive that running that risk is never worth it.

On top of that your processing of the files' content is flawed, because the inner loop processes the content one line at a time, but both of your conditionals match on different lines and are not linked to each other. If you created a new object with every iteration that would give you incorrect results. Read the file as a whole and then use `Select-String` with a multiline regex to extract the desired information.

Another thing to avoid is appending to an array in a loop (that's a slow operation because it involves re-creating the array and copying elements over and over). Since you're using `ForEach-Object` you can pipe directly into `Export-Csv`.

Something like this should work:

```cs
$re = 'IF Ingroup\s+\(\s+"(.+?)"\s+\)\s+' +
      "use\s+([a-z]):\s*[`"'](\\\\[^`"'\s]+)"

Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\speterson\Documents\script\*.kiy' | ForEach-Object {
    Get-Content $_.FullName |
        Out-String |
        Select-String $re -AllMatches |
        Select-Object -Expand Matches |
        ForEach-Object {
            New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
                'Group'       = $_.Groups[1].Value
                'DriveLetter' = $_.Groups[2].Value
                'Path'        = $_.Groups[3].Value
            }
        }
} | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
```